# How can I copy an immutable object like tuple in Python?

Tags: python, types

`copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` just copy the reference for an immutable object like a tuple.
How can I create a duplicate copy of the first immutable object at a different memory location?

Comment: `oldtuple[:]` or `newtuple = tuple(oldtuple)`

Comment: why do you need to copy it anyway, if it's immutable then are you sure a reference isn't good enough?

Comment: @wim True. I expected someone to ask this. But still is there a way?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way.  I can't think of any use case where I would need two different versions of `(1, 2)` in memory.  What programming problem are you trying to solve, that is causing you to need to copy an immutable?

Comment: Consider the situation "object = (1, [child_object])" I want to modify the child_object and destroy the modification (output, or something) after use, while retaining the original

Comment: @wim When writing a custom encoder/serializer

Comment: @Eevee Please make that an answer I can vote for

Comment: @wim To add to the other valid reasons people wrote here: I came across the need for it when writing test code (testing that some code works when passed two tuples that compare equal but aren't identical). It's tiring to hear the same mantra that language designers envisioned all the valid use cases, and if you're trying to do something that doesn't fit then you're doing it wrong...

Answer (score 49):

You're looking for `deepcopy`.

```
from copy import deepcopy

tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
put = deepcopy(tup)
```

Admittedly, the ID of these two tuples will point to the same address.  Because a tuple is immutable, there's really no rationale to create another copy of it that's the exact same.  However, note that tuples can contain mutable elements to them, and deepcopy/id behaves as you anticipate it would:

```
from copy import deepcopy
tup = (1, 2, [])
put = deepcopy(tup)
tup[2].append('hello')
print tup # (1, 2, ['hello'])
print put # (1, 2, [])
```

Comment: Ids are the same for the first case, and different for the second case, tuples are well designed!

Answer (score 25):

Add the empty tuple to it:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a is a+tuple()  
False
```

Concatenating tuples always returns a new distinct tuple, even when the result turns out to be equal.

Comment: This sounds like an implementation detail rather than a guarantee.

Comment: @DietrichEpp that's true enough, and realistically `tuple(list(a))` is likewise (since nothing stops `tuple.__new__`, say, keeping weakreferences to all the tuples it has already created). There is probably *no* absolute guaranteed way to have two distinct, but equal, tuples if they only contain immutable elements.

Comment: Running the same example on python 3.8.5 from the command line gives the output `True`. Does this not work on newer versions of the language?

Comment: I got the same result on Python 3.8.6.

Comment: Doesn't work in current Python versions.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
tup = (1,2,3)
nt = tuple(list(tup))
```

Comment: adding a empty tuple is much better.

Comment: Hilariously, **this is now the only answer that actually works.** Tuples are so critical to the core functioning of Python that *all* actively maintained versions of Python now detect and memoize crude attempts to recreate recently created tuples (e.g., `a is a+tuple()`). Of course, Python can only go so far – and coercing a tuple into a list into a tuple is several steps too far. Of course, this also incurs a cost of `O(n**2)` time complexity with non-negligible constants. Of course, inefficiency is only to be expected when you intentionally break essential optimizations. *Fun stuff!*

Comment: @CecilCurry Why would it be quadratic? It's of course linear.

Answer (score 0):

This answer:

- depends on cPython implementation details (meaning that it's somewhat
  version-specific (although in practice, it hasn't been changed in a long time,
  and probably won't be changed any time soon))
- invokes C undefined behaviour
- depends on the size of pointers on your machine

This answer should NOT be used in production code in any way.  Now with the
warning/disclaimer out of the way, let's get into it.

## A preface full of pointless pedantry

First, I'm going to be pedantic about your question.  (I'm sorry, but the pedant
inside me just can't help themselves).  Let's start with the idea of
immutability.  In cPython, *nothing is immutable*.  This is because cPython
gives you access to a convenient lil' module called `ctypes`.  This allows you
to do all sorts of cool things, such as modify `tuple`s in place:

```py
>>> from ctypes import py_object as PyObject_p
>>> mutator = PyObject_p.from_address
>>> victim = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> print(victim)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> mutator(id(victim) + 40).value = "not so immutable now, are ye'?"
>>> print(victim)
(0, 1, "not so immutable now, are ye'?", 3, 4)
```

Even without `ctypes`, one could always write an extension module in something
like C and accomplish the same thing.  And then there's always just the ability
to write into the process memory directly (because `/proc/self/mem` exists),
and you can do that using plain Python (without `ctypes` or extension modules or
any of that stuff).  All of this is to say, immutability isn't real.  When
something is "immutable" in Python, all that means is that it's going to be
slightly inconvenient if you want to mutate it.

## The Answer

As per usual, the way to deal with Python's silly ideas of immutability and
safety is to ignore them.

```py
from ctypes import (
    byref as _addrof,
    sizeof as _sizeof,
    create_string_buffer as _malloc,
    cast,
    memmove as memcpy,
    c_void_p as void_p,
    py_object as PyObject_p,
)


# get the base class, since it's not publicly exposed
_ctypes_base_cls = void_p
while (_next_base := _ctypes_base_cls.__bases__[0]) is not object:
    _ctypes_base_cls = _next_base



## some utility functions that work with PyObjects as well as ctypes objects

# sizeof
def sizeof(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, _ctypes_base_cls):
        return _sizeof(obj)
    else:
        return obj.__sizeof__()

# does the same thing as `&obj` in C
def addrof(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, _ctypes_base_cls):
        return void_p(id(obj))
    return cast(_addrof(obj), void_p)

# allocate memory
def malloc(size):
    return cast(_malloc(size), void_p)

# treat something as a `PyObject *`
def as_pyobj_p(obj):
    if not isinstance(obj, _ctypes_base_cls):
        what = addrof(obj)
    return PyObject_p.from_address(addrof(obj).value)



## now for the magic...

# returns a (shallow) copy of the object
def copyobj(obj):
    copy_addr = malloc(sizeof(obj))
    memcpy(copy_addr, addrof(obj), sizeof(obj))
    return as_pyobj_p(copy_addr).value


orig = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
copy = copyobj(orig)


# Show the details of the objects:
print(f"""
original:
    {orig!r}
    {sizeof(orig)} bytes at address {hex(addrof(orig).value)}

copy:
    {copy!r}
    {sizeof(copy)} bytes at address {hex(addrof(copy).value)}


{orig is copy = }
""")
```

This is just a shallow copy, but one could construct a real deepcopy with this.
(I say "real" because Python's deepcopy is not real: it doesn't copy so-called
immutable objects, or the type information of objects (the `ob_type` member in
the `PyObject` struct), and a few other things like that.)

Enjoy!

Answer (score -4):

If You wish duplicate a tuple try

```
tup = ('a',2,obj)
dup_tup = tuple(tup)
```

in this case we created a new tuple: we can change it without changing the first.

If we use `sec_tup = tup` in this case we have two tuple but changing one the change is done also in the other

Comment: **Tuples are immutable.** Statements like "we can change it" are nonsensical. No, you *cannot* change it. That's the whole point of tuples. `</facepalm>`