# How to prevent value change in python

Tags: python

For example:

```
>>> state = (5,[1,2,3])
>>> current_state = state
>>> state[1].remove(3)
>>> state
(5, [1, 2])
>>> current_state
(5, [1, 2])
```

I changed the state but not current_state. How to keep the current_state value that equals (5,[1,2,3]) instead of removing 3 in python?

thanks!

Comment: Another option [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214404/how-can-i-copy-an-immutable-object-like-tuple-in-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) `state`, so it and `current_state` refer to different objects:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> state = (5,[1,2,3])
>>> current_state = deepcopy(state)
>>> state[1].remove(3)
>>> state
(5, [1, 2])
>>> current_state
(5, [1, 2, 3])
```